Man rejects woman sexually then she leaves him
So there's this movie where there's this unmarried couple. I think they sit down on a couch or bed and then they talk and probably drink.
The woman says she's hot so she starts removing some of her (Black?) clothing. The man asks if he should turn on the airconditioning. She says no.
After a few minutes, she starts kissing him. Then, she stars sexually advancing on him. The man rejects her saying that what is good about their relationship is that there is no physical aspect in their relationship.
Later on, she leaves him presumably because of that.
From what I remember, anyway. I suspect this was an American film sometime from 1990-2009
Damn. This sounds generic. Just trying my luck here since I was so amazed by this.

I think you are looking for
the mirror has two faces

which is a 1996 movie
 

You added picture, and our comments are gone?

wow I just saw it! I have no idea how this works!

Mod probably deleted for being chatty. You added the pic though?

Oh then he'll probably delete this one too :). yes I added the picture to improve my answer
